# Silex Framework, no route found for POST

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, routes, silex

I have a little problem with the silex framework (I'm quite sure, that it's caused by Silex)..

I have a form and want to submit it with POST, but Silex throws the following exceptions:

MethodNotAllowedException in UrlMatcher.php line 101:

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouterListener.php line 149:
No route found for "POST /checkPW": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)

Thats what my controller looks like:

```
$app->get('/checkPW', function () use ($app) {
return $app['templating']->render(
    'checkPW_blog.php'
);
});
```

And that's what the form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="/checkPW">
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"
                                                           name="password"
                                                           placeholder="Passwort">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitPW">
                                                    Passwort bestätigen
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

(realised with Bootstrap)

The bizarre thing is, that when I send the form with the method GET instead of POST everything works fine...

Does anybody know whats the problem here..?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, you only define a route for `get`:

```
$app->get('/checkPW', function () use ($app) {
  return $app['templating']->render(
    'checkPW_blog.php'
  );
});
```

Just define one for [`post`](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#example-post-route):

```
$app->post('/checkPW', function () use ($app) {
  // do post stuff...
});
```